# Warning in PHPUnit using dataProvider and Function as result

Tags: phpunit, warnings

I wrote a method to test my code , but problem is when I use `dataProvider` i got :

> `1) Warning
>   The data provider specified for userTest::testItCanValidateApiKeysAndDomainAutoTest is invalid.
>   Call to undefined function show_message()`
>
> `WARNINGS!`
>   `Tests: 5, Assertions: 12, Warnings: 1.`

here is my code when i use it without dataProvider

```
public function testItCanValidateApiKeysAndDomainByInputData(){
    $this->user->setApiKey('306942ac');
    $this->user->setDomain('test.com');
    $this->assertEquals(show_message(103), $this->user->verifyPurchaseKey());
}
```

and it work fantastic , but when i use dataProvider

```
public function inputApiKeys()
{
    return array(
        array(
            'f5e47ee75672b855a8d76f5d54aa7ce6914',
            'reza.com',
            false,
        ),
        array(
            'f5e47asdasdasd',
            'reza.com',
            show_message(100),
        ),
        array(
            '0ecc580a009d929b13337509721a4',
            'test12.com',
            show_message(102),
        ),
        array(
            '0ecc580a009d9230604659b13337509721a4',
            '127.0.0.1',
            show_message(1,
                '6233c772-e214-a45d8c1e04e2'),
        ),
        array(
            '0ecc580a009d9204659b13337509721a4',
            'localhost',
            show_message(1,
                '6233c772a45d8c1e04e2'),
        ),
        array(
            'ac45e9ff50c5aac05d25c2605d2195f33b4',
            'mm.mu.com',
            show_message(102),
        ),
        array(
            'ac45e9f1aeab519f50c5aac05d25c2605d2195f33b4',
            'reza.wpengine.com',
            show_message(103),
        ),
        array(
            '000604659b13337509721a4',
            'mnm.wpengine.com',
            '6233c772-3-9cc4-a45d8c1e04e2'),
    );
}

/**
 * @dataProvider inputApiKeys
 */
public function testItCanValidateApiKeysAndDomainAutoTest($apikey, $domain, $result)
{
    $this->user->setApiKey($apikey);
    $this->user->setDomain($domain);
    $this->assertEquals($result, $this->user->verifyPurchaseKey());
}
```

you may consider that i use show_message in another file loaded by autoload to project ..
got warning message ..

Comment: dataProviders are invoked before `setUp` or `setUpBeforeClass` methods. Do you include the `show_message` function in any of those places?

Comment: nope , i use show_message() in another file called config.php and expect it to autoload with bootstrap

Answer (score 2):

It's important to return the created data structure at the end of your data provider function:

```
return $reza;
```

This should normally make it work. At least I tried your code and it works here if I declare a `show_message()` function globally.

The message `Call to undefined function show_message()` indicates that this function is not in the scope of your data provider. That seems strange if calling `show_message()` directly in your test function works. So I think, there might be something more different in your code when you didn't use the the data provider.

Comment: sorry about the code , i was debuggig and it was the old one , in the the code i return the array and its still not working.

Comment: I extended my answer regarding the `call to undefined function` message. Pls check where `show_message()` is defined.